# how to edit text in a pdf using coldfusion?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I want to use regex to find and replace (with alternate text) all instances of email addresses in an existing pdf using coldfusion - is this possible?

Comment: Possibly.  If this were my problem, the first thing I would attempt would be to attempt to read the contents of the pdf and store them into a variable.

Comment: Thanks Dan - yes that part I think I would be ok with - it's more the updating the pdf once i've made my changes that I've not managed to find anything on. ie CF seems to offer a way to read all the text in a pdf but there doesn't seem to be anything about writing to the pdf / editing the text in the pdf.. That's the key part I think..

Comment: If you have the text in a variable, can't you simply use cfdocument to create a new pdf file?  Then you can use cffile to replace the old one.

Comment: While you can extract text and manipulate it, that is all it is - plain text.  [Pdf's are not designed for editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679505/editing-pdf-text-using-java-and-itext).

Comment: There are a couple of email regex patterns out there. But beware. It's not trivial and emails can have quite unexpected formats.

Answer (score 0):

the cfpdf tag has an action of read and write, to and from a variable, in between which you can manipulate the data with the regex function of your choice, perhaps ReReplace().

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html

```
<cfpdf action="read|write">
```

Comment: Thanks Walter - I'm not sure how one would maintain the formatting when writing the changed (by regex) data that one had read previously.. unless I'm missing something?