# Replace a word in PDF using iTextSharp in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I want to replace a specific word in existing PDF file using iTextSharp.I did a lot of research but couldn't find proper way. Can somebody share some sample code to do this?

Comment: You are confusing the Portable Document Format (PDF) with a Word processing format. Please read the intro of [Chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/3c9ca46-76da-4de2-8972-b82efbe0bf88/samplechapter6.pdf) to understand why your assumption that you can replace a specific word in an existing PDF *using any software* is wrong.

Comment: Note that this is a duplicate of [Editing PDF text using Java and Itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679505/editing-pdf-text-using-java-and-itext)

Comment: I want to use iTextSharp dll (progamitacally) to replace the string in my PDF not by using any software.

Comment: Er... the iTextSharp DLL is software. I am telling you that you are trying to do something that is **not done** in general.

Comment: Sorry but I also have to agree with Bruno. The reason that you couldn't find a "proper" was is that it doesn't exist. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29602320/231316) also does a great job of going over the very top level things

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTextSharp Replace Text in existing PDF without loosing formation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600750/itextsharp-replace-text-in-existing-pdf-without-loosing-formation)